# Hooks in Kafka Listener

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, slf4j, spring-kafka, mdc

Is there any sort of hooks available before / after kafka listen a message ?

Use case : 
MDC co-relation id has to be set for to perform the log traceability

What I am looking for ? 
A before/after call back method so that MDC co-relation id can be set on entry and eventually clean MDC upon exit.

**Edited Scenario:** 
I am getting co-relation id as a part of Kafka Headers and I want to set the same in MDC as soon as I receive a message in Kafka Listener

Appreciated for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an around advice to your listener bean...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So59854374Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So59854374Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public static BeanPostProcessor bpp() { // static is important
        return new BeanPostProcessor() {

            @Override
            public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (bean instanceof MyListener) {
                    ProxyFactoryBean pfb = new ProxyFactoryBean();
                    pfb.setTarget(bean);
                    pfb.addAdvice(new MethodInterceptor() {

                        @Override
                        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
                            try {
                                System.out.println("Before");
                                return invocation.proceed();
                            }
                            finally {
                                System.out.println("After");
                            }
                        }

                    });
                    return pfb.getObject();
                }
                return bean;
            }

        };
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so59854374").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> template.send("so59854374", "foo");
    }

}

@Component
class MyListener {

    @KafkaListener(id = "so59854374", topics = "so59854374")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

and

```
Before
foo
After
```

**EDIT**

If you add `@Header("myMdcHeader") byte[] mdc` as an additional parameter to your kafka listener method, you can use `getArguments()[1]` on the invocation.

Another solution is to add a `RecordInterceptor` to the listener container factory, which allows you to access the raw `ConsumerRecord` before it is passed to the listener adapter.

```java
/**
 * An interceptor for {@link ConsumerRecord} invoked by the listener
 * container before invoking the listener.
 *
 * @param <K> the key type.
 * @param <V> the value type.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 2.2.7
 *
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RecordInterceptor<K, V> {

    /**
     * Perform some action on the record or return a different one.
     * If null is returned the record will be skipped.
     * @param record the record.
     * @return the record or null.
     */
    @Nullable
    ConsumerRecord<K, V> intercept(ConsumerRecord<K, V> record);

}
```

```
/**
 * Set an interceptor to be called before calling the listener.
 * Does not apply to batch listeners.
 * @param recordInterceptor the interceptor.
 * @since 2.2.7
 */
public void setRecordInterceptor(RecordInterceptor<K, V> recordInterceptor) {
    this.recordInterceptor = recordInterceptor;
}
```

If you are using a batch listener, Kafka provides a `ConsumerInterceptor`.

Comment: The problem here is , we cannot set the runtime corelation id . This is the error

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; please clarify by editing the question. The method arguments are available in the `invocation`.