# Spring Boot @JmsListener Interceptor

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

In my application I have messages moving from one queue to another, and I want to add message ID in my logs. I am trying to figure out if I can intercept message before being actually processed and set message ID in MDC fields so that I can track this message across all the queues. I have not had success so far. Is there any existing solution?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59854374/hooks-in-kafka-listener/59862124#59862124) about a similar question about `@KafkaListener`; you can use the same technique here.

Comment: That works @GaryRussell but then I cannot access message attributes. Is there any message context somewhere in jms components which I can override or access to get message attibutes for logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That works but then I cannot access message attributes. Is there any message context somewhere in jms components which I can override or access to get message attibutes for logging?

You can either add the raw JMS `Message` (or just the message id property) as an additional parameter to the `@JmsListener` (and access it with `invocation.getArguments()`) or you can wrap the entire listener adapter instead of just your listener bean. Use the container registry to get a reference to the container, then `container.setMessageListener(wrap(container.getMessageListener()));`.